# Convert the distance from decimal to integer if need

Tags: android

I want to calculate the distance from the user location to a lat/long. My problem is that sometimes the result of the distance is a decimal like `234,56`. In that case I want to make it an integer.What I have to do?

May I use something like this?

```
 private DecimalFormat dec2 = new DecimalFormat("#####");
```

and then

```
 String distance=dec2.format(location);
```

Comment: for example,this time i m getting 45.677 km distance.i want to make it 45 km or 46. And if it was 456.77 to make ti 456 or 457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your distance variable is of the primitive type double then you can simply do:

```
int distanceInt = (int) distanceDouble;
```

Is the distance variable a real BigDecimal object, what I could hardly believe than you can do the following

```
int distanceInt = distanceBigDecimal.intValue();
```

Comment: i just solved it myself..silly question!Anyway,thanks for your answer!:)